# How to upload CSV file in google drive in swift 3

Tags: ios, csv, swift3, google-drive-api

I am using google drive SDK for uploading CSV file. I used code given in google but error is coming

```
func create(){

    let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: "FL_insurance_sample.csv")

    let folderId: String = self.fileId!
    let metadata = GTLRDrive_File.init()
    metadata.name = "FL_insurance_sample"
    metadata.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
    metadata.parents = [folderId]


    let uploadParameters = GTLRUploadParameters(data: fileData! , mimeType: "text/csv")
    uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = true
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: metadata, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)
    query.fields = "id"
    self.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, object:Any?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            //  print("File ID \(files.identifier)")
        }
        else {
            print("An error occurred: \(error)")
        }
    })         

}
```

It showing nil error on uploadParameters at fileData. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable fileData is nil because you've passed the wrong file path. To get correct file path use:

```
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FL_insurance_sample", ofType: "csv") else {
    print("No such file in bundle")
    // handle situation
    return
}
guard let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) else {
    print("Can't read file")
    // handle situation
    return
}
// upload fileData
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply can u tell me how do i get a zip file from system to upload in drive

Comment: @Udai kumar you can do it in the same way if your zip included in apps bundle. Here you just get all the bytes from file and upload them to drive using "application/zip" mime type.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have save a zip file in system who's url is "file:///Users/marg/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1EEB75C-9DE9-491A-A160-4C35BF3D8012/data/Containers/Data/Application/6C490021-9612-4631-8016-459BFCA7453F/Documents/archive.zip" now i want to upload this file